# How to receive module ID on Opencart frontend

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I'm trying to prepare a module.
I need the module_id value.
I will draw data with the module_id value.
How do I get module_id in the controller on the front side.

Comment: Save "module_id" with module setting in admin controller file of module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion may apply to single module.

My module has sub-modules.

But I found the solution.

Design layout have solved the work with files.

```
catalog / controller / common / common_left.php
catalog / controller / common / common_right.php
catalog / controller / common / head_top.php
catalog / controller / common / head_bottom.php
```

etc.

I added a starred code.

```
    if (isset($part[1])) {
        $setting_info = $this->model_setting_module->getModule($part[1]);

        if ($setting_info && $setting_info['status']) {
        ***** $setting_info["module_id"] = $part[1]; *****
            $output = $this->load->controller('extension/module/' . $part[0], $setting_info);

            if ($output) {
                $data['modules'][] = $output;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create model file with some name mymodule.php where you should place something like this:

```
public function getModules() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "module` ORDER BY `code`");

        return $query->rows;
    }   
    you will get all modules data.
```

or can get just only one by module code:

```
public function getModulesByCode($code) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "module` WHERE `code` = '" . $this->db->escape($code) . "' ORDER BY `name`");

        return $query->rows;
    }
```

Then in your controller with corresponding name mymodule.php file you can call it:

```
 $modules = $this->model_extension_module->getModulesByCode($code);
```

or

```
$modules = $this->model_extension_module->getModules();
```

Comment: Thanks.
I solved the problem.
I published it as a reply.